# Form partial not rendering in modified Rails Tutorial app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Building the Rails Tutorial, but modifying it to build an employee timeclock app for HR purposes.  On my signup page, the form partial is not rendering in the view.

new.html.erb

```
    <% provide(:title, 'New Employee Sign-up') %>
    <% provide(:button_text, 'Register Me') %>
    <h1>Register your information</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <% render 'form' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@employee, url: newemployee_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @employee %>

      <%= f.label :firstname %>
      <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :lastname %>
      <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :ssn %>
      <%= f.text_field :ssn, class: 'form-control' %>

      <!-- <%= f.label :dateofhire %> -->
      <!-- <%= f.text_field :dateofhire, class: 'form-control' %> -->

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

(The 'date of hire' field is commented out because I don't have a regex validation and migration ready for what the field will push into the database.)

What could be responsible for the form not rendering?  [Click here to see what I'm seeing in the preview pane:](https://mv-timesheets-jtnash3705b.c9users.io)

Comment: `newemployee_path` maybe `new_employee_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `render` call.

It should be `<%= render 'form' %>` so that it outputs the result in the view.

Comment: Of course!  Without the '=', the results of the Ruby call won't be rendered in the HTML (facepalm)...